# How can VBA read CSV with breakline inside double quote?

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I'm trying to upload a `CSV file` with breaklines inside quotes (data.csv) but instead of putting all the text inside the quote in one cell, it still considers it as a new row.

When I open the CSV directly, everything works fine but when I run it through VBA, everything is getting messed up.

**data.csv sample**

```
cases,"variant:
option1: 0333102
option2: 1133202
option3: 4234442"
make-shift,"variant:
option1: shift iron
option2: workload
option3: network map
option4: lesson map"
```

**Import_CSV Function**

```
Function import_CSV(location As String, row As Integer, col As String) As Variant

Dim ws As Worksheet, strFile As String
Sheets("data").Visible = True

Sheets("data").UsedRange.ClearContents

Set ws = Sheets("data")
strFile = location

With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & strFile, Destination:=ws.Range("A1"))
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 850
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With

import_CSV = Sheets("data").Range(col & "1:" & Get_C(Last_C(row, "data")) & Last_R(Get_C(Last_C(row, "data")), "data"))
Sheets("data").Visible = False

End Function
```

Comment: What do Get_C, Last_C and Last_R do?

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald gets the last column with value. I've tested and all of it returns "A1:B1665"

Comment: Using QueryTables really doesn't work for that csv format. You really need to use QueryTable to get the data? You can simply get Excel to open the csv file and then copy it's UsedRange across.

Comment: @PatricK I'm not sure how that works using vba since this is just a part of the process. any codes for that or reference i can go to? thanks!

Comment: I think your `Function import_CSV()` returns a Range object, is it meant to be the imported range?

Comment: @PatricK yes i've pasted the imported range to a temporary sheet and returned the used range of that sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `import_CSV()` returns the range in **data** worksheet with same size as the imported CSV, try below. Don't really need the `row` integer and `col` string, so I have omitted it.

```
Option Explicit

Function ImportCustomCSV(location As String) As Range
    Dim oWbCSV As Workbook, oRngCSV As Range, oRngData As Range
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data").UsedRange.ClearContents
    ' Range to start pasting csv data
    Set oRngData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data").Range("A1")
    ' Assumes file availability is already checked
    Set oWbCSV = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=location, ReadOnly:=True)
    Set oRngCSV = oWbCSV.Worksheets(1).UsedRange
    ' Copy the CSV range to data worksheet
    oRngCSV.Copy oRngData
    ' Make the data range the same rows and cols as imported csv
    Set oRngData = oRngData.Resize(oRngCSV.Rows.Count, oRngCSV.Columns.Count)
    ' Cleanup
    Set oRngCSV = Nothing
    oWbCSV.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Set oWbCSV = Nothing
    ' Return the updated data range
    Set ImportCustomCSV = oRngData
End Function
```